# If a word as a space, put the next word onto a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to break some text up, i.e. if the word is

Screen Shot

I want it to show the shot under screen

I understand I'm going to need jquery or javascript but can anyone give me a helping hand as i don't know where to start?

Thanks

Comment: what are tried so far? have you any code for it?

Comment: where in div, textarea???

Comment: Can you precise your contexte more specifically?
You might want that:

    var text = "Screen Shot";
    text = text .replace(/\s/, '<br/>');
    $("#myContainer").append(text);

Comment: Hi, the only code I have is <div class="hero_text"> Screen Shot</div> I didn't know whether jquery could do this or if i needed javascript, so i didn't know where to start?

Comment: You never need JQuery. You can do without it.
with my code above, it would be: document.getElementById("myContainer").innerHTML =  text ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/T3UBb/3/

HTML:

```
 <div class="hero_text">Screen Shot</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".hero_text").html(function(index, text) {
   return text.replace(' ', '<br>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this help me and I actually understand how it works so again thank you. I'll mark it as answered when it lets me.

Comment: Telling people to use JQuery to do a poor replace when they don't know how javascript works is a big mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sentence = "This is a test"

var words = sentence.split(" ");
```

This will give you an array of strings ["This","is","a","test"] which you can iterate over and add each word to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it spliting the text :

```
var str = "Screen Shot";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

And you have an array (res) with values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
word.replace(' ','\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var heroElements = document.getElementsByTagName("hero_text");
for(var i = 0; i < heroElements.length; i++)
{
    var text = heroElements[i].innerText;
    text = text .replace(/\s/, '<br/>');
    heroElements[i].innerHTML = text;
}
```